# yiimongodbsuite. modify embedded document

Tags: mongodb, yii, yii-extensions

I am using yiimongodbsuite extension and I have an embedded document User in my model where I save some information about user - userId, userName, isAdmin and etc.
Now I want to modify some field in my User embedded document.
I try to do it as write here - http://canni.github.com/YiiMongoDbSuite/xhtml/advanced.partial-batch-update.html but it can modify only model fields, not fields in embedded document.
How to modify fields in embedded document?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The instructions you've referenced are for partial updates on multiple documents.

What you actually need to do is just updating a [simple embedded document](http://canni.github.com/YiiMongoDbSuite/xhtml/basic.simple-embedded-document.html).

Example for `mydoc` with embedded `user`:

```
$mydoc = new Mydoc();

// Updated embedded User document
$mydoc->user->userName = 'Fred';
$mydoc->user->isAdmin = 1;

$mydoc->save();
```